# Why do I get this segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm working on a my pre-lab in which I'm supposed to take pre-defined strings and print if they're all uppercase, lowercase, have digits, or a mixture. However, I keep getting a segmentation fault(core dumped). I tried debugging, but I have no clue what the problem is. Any help is appreciated!

This is my main.c

```
#define DIGITTEST1 "12345abcd67890"
#define DIGITTEST2 "1234567890"
#define LOWERTEST1 "hifromJimRies"
#define LOWERTEST2 "hifromjimries"
#define UPPERTEST1 "JIMRIESWASHERE"
#define UPPERTEST2 "JIMRIESWASHERe"
#define ONEMORETEST "9jimr"

void PrintCategory(char *s);

int main(void)
{
PrintCategory(DIGITTEST1);
PrintCategory(DIGITTEST2);
PrintCategory(LOWERTEST1);
PrintCategory(LOWERTEST2);
PrintCategory(UPPERTEST1);
PrintCategory(UPPERTEST2);
PrintCategory(ONEMORETEST);
}
```

This is my stringfunc.c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    #define DIGITTEST1 "12345abcd67890"
    #define DIGITTEST2 "1234567890"
    #define LOWERTEST1 "hifromJimRies"
    #define LOWERTEST2 "hifromjimries"
    #define UPPERTEST1 "JIMRIESWASHERE"
    #define UPPERTEST2 "JIMRIESWASHERe"
    #define ONEMORETEST "9jimr"

void PrintCategory(char *s)
{
  if (isdigit (DIGITTEST1))
    {
      printf ("%s is all digits\n", DIGITTEST1);
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("%s is a mix of various types of characters\n", DIGITTEST1);
    }

  if (isdigit (DIGITTEST2))
    {
      printf ("%s is all digits\n", DIGITTEST2);
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("%s is a mix of various types of characters\n", DIGITTEST2);
    }
  if (islower (LOWERTEST1))
    {
      printf ("%s is all lower case\n", LOWERTEST1);
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("%s is a mix of various types of characters\n", LOWERTEST1);
    }
  if (islower (LOWERTEST2))
    {
      printf ("%s is all lower case\n", LOWERTEST2);
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("%s is a mix of various types of characters\n", LOWERTEST2);
    }
  if (isupper (UPPERTEST1))
    {
      printf ("%s is all upper casae\n", UPPERTEST1);
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("%s is a mix of various types of characters\n", UPPERTEST1);
    }
  if (isupper (UPPERTEST2))
    {
      printf ("%s is all upper case\n", UPPERTEST2);
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("%s is a mix of various types of characters\n", UPPERTEST2);
    }
  if (islower (ONEMORETEST))
    {
      printf ("%s is all lower case\n", ONEMORETEST);
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("%s is a mix of various types of characters\n", ONEMORETEST);
    }

}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, you should get messages about the use of `isdigit`

Comment: The `is` functions take a `char`. You are passing them a string.

Comment: @kaylum in fact they take an `int` value which must be in the range 0 to UCHAR_MAX

Comment: @M.M Yep you are right. My bad. Hopefully OP won't be confused by that and understands the underlying issue.

Comment: Unrelated but what is the point of passing in `s` which is ignored in the function? I don't think the intent of the task is for your function to hard code all the checks inside the function. Instead the function should do the checks on a the passed in string. And `main` or the test driver can pass in the different strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your passing character array to isdigit function as shown below here.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005cf in PrintCategory (s=0x400880 "12345abcd67890") at String.c:13
13    if (isdigit (DIGITTEST1))
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-292.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

The functions from ctype.h (e.g. `isdigit`, `islower`, etc.) are working on characters. Their argument is of type `int`. However, you pass a string (type `char *`) to it. This does compile, because a `char *` *can* be implicitly converted to `int`. However, in this case the code is incorrect and results in undefined behavior (in this case a segmentation fault).

The compiler warns you about this error. For example, when I compile your code I get the following warnings:

```
stringfunc.c: In function ‘PrintCategory’:
stringfunc.c:13:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
stringfunc.c:22:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
stringfunc.c:30:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
stringfunc.c:38:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
stringfunc.c:46:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
stringfunc.c:54:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
stringfunc.c:62:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

I highly recommend to compile with compiler options `-Wall` and `-Werror` if using gcc (other compiler might have similar options) to avoid these kind of programming errors. Using `-Werror` this code would not have compiled.

Comment: `char*` cannot be implicitly converted to `int` in Standard C, there must be a diagnostic generated

Comment: @M.M, yes, but a diagnostic is not an error. The code from the question _can_ be compiled but results in an incorrect program. That's why I recommend `-Werror`, which will avoid generating such incorrect program

Comment: (NB: This also means it *can* be implicitly converted to int.)

Comment: The standard only has "diagnostics" without further division , and the program violates a constraint (so the behaviour is not defined , since the behaviour is only defined for programs that don't violate constraints)

Comment: @M.M I agree with your last comment, but that's exactly what answers the question of the OP, right? A `char *` _can_ be implicitly converted to `int`, although that's in many cases not logical, hence the standard requires to generate a warning, and if you ignore this warning and still run the incorrect program (with undefined behavior) you might get a segmentation fault. Am I missing another point you are trying to make? Do you have a suggestion of how to improve my answer?

Comment: It can't in Standard C , and my suggestion is to not say that it can, and also not say "This compiles correctly" since in fact it must generate a diagnostic and the compiler may reject the program.    Your explanation of "can" is like saying that `asdfaslwfewfw` can be a C program because the compiler might accept it (whilst issuing a diagnostic),  i.e. not a very useful definition of "can"

Comment: @M.M, I agree the phrase "compiles correctly" might be confusing and I have updated the text accordingly. I still think that the code "can" be compiled, because in fact it _does_ result in a binary (which crashes, and causes the OP to ask this question). But I hope my answer is more clear now.